# Converting package object contents from scala to java

Tags: scala

I have the unfortunate task of converting a networking library that I wrote couple years back from `scala` to `java` due to lack of offshore `scala` resources.

One of the tricker areas : converting the `package` object and its `type aliases` and `case classes`. Here is an excerpt:

```
package object xfer {

  type RawData = Array[Byte]
  type DataPtr = String

  type PackedData = RawData
//  type PackedData = (DataPtr, RawData, RawData)
//  type UnpackedData = (DataPtr, Any, RawData)
  type UnpackedData = Any

  case class TaggedEntry(tag: String, data: Array[Byte])

  case class TypedEntry[T](tag: String, t: T)

  case class XferWriteParams(tag: String, config: XferConfig, data: RawData, md5: RawData) {

    override def toString: DataPtr = s"XferWriteParams: config=$config datalen=${data.length}} md5len=${md5.length}}"
  }
```

As an example the `RawData` has 32 usages.  I suppose that one approach could be to do simple *Find/Replace* of all 32 instances with `byte[]`: but is there a more elegant way?

For the `case class`'es .. I'm leery of creating another few top level files in this package for each of them - and likewise another few top level files in each of a dozen other packages .. but is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADT-esque trait-case-class clusters like

```
trait T
case class C1 extends T
case class C2 extends T
```

could be converted to an abstract base class `T`, with nested static classes `C1`, `C2`:

```
abstract class T {
  static class C1 extends T { ... }
  static class C2 extends T { ... }
}
```

This would at least eliminate the need to explode each such enumeration into thousand top-level classes in separate files.

For type-aliases, you might consider promoting them to full fledged wrapper classes, but you would have to be very careful whenever instantiating classes like `RawData`, using `==`/`equals`, `hashCode`, or putting them in `HashSet`s or `HashMap`s. Something like this might work:

```
class RawData {
    private final byte[] value;
    public RawData(byte[] v) { ... }
    public byte[] getValue() { ... }

    public static RawData of(byte[] value) {
      return new RawData(value);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return value.hashCode();
    }
    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof RawData) {
            return value.equals(((RawData) other).value);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

This would keep the signatures similar, and might even enhance type-safety to some extent. In cases where it is really performance critical, I'd propose to just find/replace all occurrences by `byte[]`.

Comment: You probably don't want to forget `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` on the wrapper, and of course on the case classes...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov In case of byte arrays, you actually don't want to override `hashCode` or `equals`, because the original `type RawData = Array[Byte]` also have just the referential equality, anything else would change the semantics. Anyway, I tried to insinuate that something might be missing with the "..."s. I don't know, what do they do in Java nowadays? Still generating boilerplate with the IDE? Or has some other robust solution (maybe Lombok?) emerged?

Comment: I would expect two `RawData` wrappers of the same array instance being unequal to be more likely to break original code. Because to satisfy signatures you may need to end up inserting constructor and `getValue` calls several times.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Ok, what about unwrapping `value` during `equals` comparison, and redirecting `hashCode` to the `value`? It should respect the `hashCode`-`equals` contract. It would break equality if a `RawValue` is compared from the right with a `byte[]` on the left though... Not sure whether this could be avoided somehow.

Comment: "Ok, what about unwrapping value during equals comparison, and redirecting hashCode to the value? It should respect the hashCode-equals contract." Yes, that's how it should be implemented. And for comparing `RawValue` with a `byte[]`... hope nobody did that? :)

Comment: @javadba Oh and _don't_ forget `==` in Scala is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object- in Java (to handle `null` correctly).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Hm... No, actually, it breaks symmetry of `equals`, because, as I said, `byte[]` `equals` `RawData` (in that order) will always return `false`... I guess it's better to remove the confusing code block altogether. Any other ideas how to deal with type aliases would be appreciated, I guess...